# Draw the graph polar coordinates

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

Draw the graph $r=3\cos a$  and  write me how do you this?
Show me polar coordinates system $a=360°$.

Comment: You're saying $a$ is 360 degrees? Wouldn't that make $r=3$, whose graph is a circle?

Comment: @79037662 $r=3$ **and** $a=360^\circ$ is only a point $(3,0)$

Comment: @Andrei Didn't realize $a$ was the angle coordinate, I thought it was a constant (and given to equal 360 degrees).

Answer (score 0):

$$r=3\cos\alpha\\x=r\cos\alpha\\y=r\sin\alpha$$
From here $$y=3\sin\alpha\cos\alpha=\frac 32\sin(2\alpha)\\x=3\cos^2\alpha=\frac 32\cos(2\alpha)-\frac 32$$
Moving the last term in $x$ to the left hand side, squaring the two equations, and summing them, you get $$\left(x-\frac 32\right)^2+y^2=\left(\frac32\right)^2$$
This is the equation of a circle with radius $1.5$ and center at $(1.5,0)$